# How can I plug this .tga mask node into a gltf 2.0 file?

Tags: texturing, masking, gltf

[image]

Until then the Blender documentation gives instructions for applying the metal texture, roughness, opacity and normal map to glTF files. I've been googling it a lot and I didn't find anything right.

What this file does or is supposed to do is provide transparency with mirrors and glass.

Comment: Is the "mask" really an alpha channel? You could try plugging it into the Alpha input of Principled BSDF, but you also need to set the material's blend mode to Alpha Blend for that to have any effect.  However, if you're looking to make glass, like a car windshield, you might consider using a separate material with "transmission" turned on.  [Also, for glTF you can't multiply AO with the base color like you're doing here, check the docs on how to apply AO correctly.]

Comment: Hey, thanks for giving me an answer. You gave the right example, it is the glass of a car although it is also similar to another case of a magnifying glass. 

The material (normal color) connected to the Alpha of BSDF of Alpha Blend in Evee gave result although on the place that it did not have to give it, as if it were upside down.

Comment: I was checking and there is a way to connect an AO node. Is it something similar to [this?](https://docs.blender.org/manual/es/2.91/_images/addons_import-export_scene-gltf2_material-occlusion-only.png)